# max_allowed_packet in my.cnf is not reflected in MySql 5.7

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, max-allowed-packet

We have changed the value of "max_allowed_packet" in my.cnf to

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 200M
```

but, when we `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';`, we get the "max_allowed_packet" as 4194304.

We tried to `set global max_allowed_packet=209715200;`, but we get "Packet for query is too large (41867758 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable." error.

Comment: is your server running on a vm ?

Comment: No. It is on Mac machine

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @ghadeer  What is the result displayed when you  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';  ?    This is different than SHOW VARIABLE LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'; that will display the 'session' value for the variable.